# RegEx: Extended or

Tags: php, regex, dokuwiki

I'm using RegEx to get specific parts of a file via PHP!

Let me show you an input-example:

```
=== KEYWORD1 ===
CONTENT

==== ANOTHERKEYWORD ====

CONTENT2

=== TESTKEYWORD ===

CONTENT3
```

My ReGex now might be: `$pattern = "/.*=+ SEARCHTERM =+(.*?)=+.*=+.*/s";`

`SEARCHTERM` is the flexible part of my regex.

Here an overview about what I expect to get and what I do receive:

- When *SEARCHTERM* is replaced with **KEYWORD1** I expect `CONTENT` but do get nothing
- When *SEARCHTERM* is replaced with **ANOTHERKEYWORD** I expect `CONTENT2`and do get it (so this case works
- When *SEARCHTERM* is replaced with **TESTKEYWORD** I expect `CONTENT3` and get nothing

So the critical part is that there *can be but don't has to be* an empty line beyond the Searchterm **AND** that the RegEx first has to look if there is any other === ANYTHING === after SEARCHTERM and only if there is none, read everything 'till the files end.

I thought of `$pattern = "/.*=+ SEARCHTERM =+(.*?)[=+.*=+.*|.*]/";` but this throws syntaxErrors.

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
$str = <<<EOD
=== KEYWORD1 ===
CONTENT

==== ANOTHERKEYWORD ====

CONTENT2

=== TESTKEYWORD ===

CONTENT3    

EOD;

foreach(array('KEYWORD1', 'ANOTHERKEYWORD', 'TESTKEYWORD') as $keyword) {
    preg_match("/.*=+ $keyword =+([^=]+)/m", $str, $m);
    echo "$keyword -> $m[1]\n";;
}
```

**output:**

```
KEYWORD1 ->
CONTENT


ANOTHERKEYWORD ->

CONTENT2


TESTKEYWORD ->

CONTENT3
```

Comment: Assuming keyword doesn't contain '='. I feel this better idea than using `.+` (so global character allowed in keyword).